# A few histograms, each with different data but all of them having the same bin width and no gaps between bins

Tags: highcharts

I have a few histograms. Each of them have different data. How can I make the bar width the same across all histograms and no gaps between bars ?

[Here's an example of my histograms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xLCj.png)

Answer (score 1):

To set bar width you need to set [`pointWidth`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.histogram.pointWidth)

> A pixel value specifying a fixed width for each column or bar. When null, the width is calculated from the pointPadding and groupPadding.

You can't set the distance between the bars the same without resizing what you see. That means you either have to set the size of the highcharts div appropriately, or you need to set min and max for the chart so that the same number of bars will be in each histogram.

Comment: pointWidth adds gaps between bars or gets bars overlapped. [See the second chart after adding pointWidth](https://jsfiddle.net/developer111/hxe50tbr/17/).

Comment: Yes, that is what I said above. You need to have the same number of bars, or it will look different.